# vite:build-html EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: github, github-pages

`npm run build

> hiddal.com@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v4.1.1 building for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
**[vite:build-html] EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read**
file: C:/Users/hgale/alexanderhdev/Hiddal/hiddal.com/index.html
**error during build:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read**

I still couldn't find solutions because I can't understand the error`

Answer (score 2):

EISDIR means Error is a Directory. It means your code is trying to run a directory as a file. That can mean a lot of things.
Maybe you're trying to import a directory's `index.js` file, for example:
`import concatenate from "@/helpers"`.

Are you importing anything `from "hiddal.com"` ? If so, I would try explicitly importing the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, When  I'm deploying the tailwindcss Html file using "npm run build" , I got this error and It is a simple file destination or incomplete url destination error in between src of img/video tags. So, just remove img/video tag(If necessary) or replace with appropriate file path.

[As you can see there i provided a incomplete url at line:1055](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4H4f.png)

[And error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cotET.png)